# automated login for rocketchat user within iframe embedded in an angular 6 component

Tags: angular, mongodb, iframe, rocket.chat

I am attempting to login users automatically into my rocketchat server via my angular 6 application/component ( where users are already required to login).

Does anyone have any experience directly manipulating the mongodb to login a user with rocket chat? I can update the database with a generated token, but cannot get iframe to read/accept the generated token.

I have direct access to the mongodb/rocketchat database which I am attempting to manipulate to store a token for login access. I am storing a generated token (I am using a UUID) onto the user document under the fields
services: { iframe: "generated-token" }
where generated-token is replaced with my uuid.

I set the same token under window.localstorage and post a message as requested in the documentation here: https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/iframe-integration/authentication/#managing-mongodb-directly

For the life of me I cannot get this to work. I am not getting any errors in the console - so it doesnt appear to be a CORS issue.

The rocketchat server whilst in development is hosted on a separate machine on my network (http://project-mgr:3000).

I am using my local machine for development (http://localhost:4000).

```
//component
login() {
      //retrieve a list of rocketchat users from mdb
      this.rocketService.allUsers().subscribe((au) => {
          //retrieve current user from mdb
          let user = au[this.user.mail]; // 

          //generate token
          let token = API.UUID();

          //manipulate rocketchat mdb entry with token info
          user.services = { iframe: token }

          //update mdb entry for user
          this.rocketService.login(user).subscribe(() => {

            //set local storage with token info
            window.localStorage.setItem("Meteor.userId", user._id);
            window.localStorage.setItem("Meteor.loginToken", token);

            //post message
            window.parent.postMessage({
            event: 'try-iframe-login'
          }, 'http://localhost:4000');
        });
      })
  }

ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('message', (event:any) =>
          console.log(event)
     );

    this.subscriptions.push(
      //retrieve currently logged in user
      this.authService.user.subscribe((u) => {
        this.user = new User(u);

        //login to rocket chat
        this.login();
        }))
  }

//html - not safe, but for development only

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="stretch"
style="height:calc(100vh - 80px);width:100%;">

  <iframe #rocketChat frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"
  sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms allow-top-navigation allow-popups
          allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" [src]="'http://project-mgr:3000' | safe: 'resourceUrl'">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

The login interface for rocketchat does not change ( or login ) but there are two messages generated from the event subscription.

They have event data:

data: ""
eventName: "unread-changed"

and

data: true
eventName: "startup"

I have not been able to figure out if that is useful or irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

To do so is a straight forward, Rocket Chat iframe integration made it easy to send commands to an iframe, one of those commands is 'login-with-token'.

First, you need to configure rocket chat server to accept iframe integration:

```
Administration -> General -> iframe integration
```

[image: iframe integration]

and based on the web/ui technology that you are using, add the following code to your html page:

```
//Read the following values based on the web site development technology you are using
//You might need also to create the group/user if not exist, and then add user to the group

    string authToken = "####"; //after you sign in the user
    string groupName = "GGGG"; //after you create a group (if not)
    string channelLink = "https://your.rchat.url.com/channel/" + groupName + "?layout=embedded";


//now use the channelLink in the iFrame
<iframe id="rcChannel" name="rcChannel" src="@channelLink" width="400" height="700"></iframe>



//And here you can authenticate the IFrame
<script>
    function authenticateIFrame() {
        document.getElementById('rcChannel').contentWindow.postMessage({
            externalCommand: 'login-with-token',
            token: '@authToken'
        }, '*');
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        authenticateIFrame();
    };
</script>
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: can you please let me know what will be the 
Iframe URL and Api URL which we need to add for Iframe inside admin panel,in this case because I have applied your solution and it is not working for me.?

Comment: @usama no need to use IFrame and API URLs, those URLs are used only if you need to provide your own Login screen for rocket chat. What I showed here is how to use Iframe out of the box, you need only to authenticate the user using login API and pass the token you receive to the iframe authentication through a post message.

Comment: thanks for replying to me, I have disabled the Iframe and removed the  Iframe URL and Api URL to, and I have tried enabling the Rest Api cors and I have enabled the Administration -> General -> iframe integration just like you have explained in your answer, but after doing that I am facing this issue and the login to the Iframe is not working, Now I am getting this message in console "Blocked autofocusing on a form control in a cross-origin subframe." , Can you please let me know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: @usama would you please create a new question, reference the question here, and list your code in that question so I can help you better :)

Comment: Hi @Shadi, i have some problems doing something like this, can you help me please? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68133150/how-to-log-a-user-in-rocketchat-from-an-iframe-and-using-the-authtoken-returned)

Comment: @JayAndJay I answered your question, please check my answer.