# Rocket Chat, Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'

Tags: authentication, iframe, browser, cross-domain, rocket.chat

In my web application I used `iframe` to load "RocketChat" chat instance. But when I tried to login to rocket chat using `window.postMessage()` browser gives me a console error. please find the below screen shot.

[Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://haulmatic.rocket.chat') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3030').](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyFzg.jpg)

```
axios.post('https://myDomain.rocket.chat/api/v1/login', {
            username: '<myUserName>',
            password: '<myPassword>'
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.status === 'success') {
                res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                res.send(`
                <iframe id="iframe" width="400px" height="900px" src="https://myDomain.rocket.chat?origin=http://localhost:3030"></iframe>
                <script>
                    window.parent.postMessage({
                        event: 'login-with-token',
                        loginToken: '${ response.data.data.authToken }'
                    }, 'https://myDomain.rocket.chat/'); // rocket.chat's URL   206.189.138.6:3000
                </script> 
                `);
            }
        }).catch(function() {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        });
```

[Reference : rocket chat iframe authentication documentation](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/iframe-integration/authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a command to the iframe with a valid user token who is already a member in the channel you are browsing in the iframe.

Here is my detailed answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58820488/628592