# How to log a user in RocketChat from an iframe and using the authToken returned by the REST API

Tags: angular, iframe, rocket.chat

I am embedding RocketChat in an iframe on my website in angular. Ideally, when the user authenticates to my REST API, authenticate them using the RocketChat REST API and use the (RocketChat) token to authenticate them within the Iframe.
I have tried to authenticate the user using the token returned by the RocketChat REST API in a number of ways but it has not worked. This is my test code:

Template:

```
<iframe
  #iframe
  id="iframe"
  src="https://myrocketchat.example.com/channel/general?layout=embedded"
  (load)="onIframeLoad()">
</iframe>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('iframe', { static: false, read: ElementRef })
private iframe: ElementRef;

onIframeLoad() {
    this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.postMessage({
      event: 'login-with-token',
      loginToken: 'LNpNjcARrh-GBwP8dxO5TEwLUwCP2lEIcRB5-GKGalX' // I get this token using Postman against the RocketChat REST API
    }, '*');
}
```

This way it doesn't work, I keep getting the window to log into the iframe.
I also tried calling a Meteor object in the iframe, But it gives CROSS-ORIGIN problems

```
this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.Meteor.loginWithToken('LNpNjcARrh-GBwP8dxO5TEwLUwCP2lEIcRB5-GKGalX');

DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://client-angular.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two points over here, first I can see that you are not using the right attribute for the postMessage, you have to use `'externalCommand'` instead of `'event'` for the `'login-with-token'`. Change this and test your code.

If the first step didn't solve your issue, then the second point is about the timing of authenticating your session on rocket chat, I'm afraid that `'onIframeLoad'` event will be loaded before it gets authenticated, use the `window.onload` for example, this event will happen before loading the iframe.

```
window.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage({
          externalCommand: 'login-with-token',
          loginToken: 'LNpNjcARrh-GBwP8dxO5TEwLUwCP2lEIcRB5-GKGalX'
          }, '*');
};
```

Comment: I just activated setting / accounts / iframe (leaving both URLs blank) and the user accesses without problems. Thanks for your quick response